# Inputting a matrix into a function syntax vba

Tags: function, vba, matrix

I have a function that inputs a matrix, and outputs a matrix. I am calling it in this line of code.

```
cholesky = Application.WorksheetFunction.Cholesky2(covar)
```

The error I am getting is "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

cholesky is declared as:

```
dim cholesky() as variant
```

and covar is declared as:

```
dim covar(2,2) as double
```

My guess is that there is some sort of silly syntax error here that I am not aware of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a worksheet function, hence you're getting the error

Simply write

```
choelsky = choelskyfunction(covar(2,2))
```

and it should work.

P.S. Also use different names for the variable and the function.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. Now unfortunately I think it is just inputting the value of covar at (2,2), and not the whole matrix. Is this syntax correct? I'm getting an error thrown at me within the function.

Comment: That would depend entirely on how you've implemented the decomposition function. The way I see it, covar(2,2) is not generating a matrix, you'll need to generate a variant matrix and feed it to the ch.decomposition function.

Comment: so do something like, dim temp as variant, temp = covar, cholesky = cholesky2(temp)?

Comment: yup, something like that.